# Nodejs Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1

Tags: node.js

after updating NodeJS to v0.10.29 I got the following error:

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1.
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/home/masiar/usi_liquid_streams/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/masiar/usi_liquid_streams/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Executing `sudo npm update` did not work. I installed back version v0.10.15 (was using that one before), ran `sudo npm update` and uninstalled and installed back `jsdom` gave the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are totally uninstalling and deleting the whole module?

Comment: `sudo npm uninstall jsdom` should work, right? After uninstalling it I tried to run my program to double-check that, and indeed an error prompted saying the module was missing. By installing it back I get the same error described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is usually happened when upgrading node version. You are in this scenario: you are using Node for example version 5. You add some libraries inside your project, build and run that. All your libraries will be compiled under node version 5.

And then you upgrade your node for example to version 6. And then you run some commands that using node, for example npm run test. The problem is here: you use newer node version for running libraries that compiled by older node.

Solving this is easy by 2 following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules // force remove node_modules directory
npm install         // install again all libraries. Libraries will be compiled again with new node version
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Well, some time passed, but I got more proficient with NodeJS and yeah, I think the issue may be caused by that.